# Extract data from multiple webpage - Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

Can someone help me to xxtract data from multiple webpage in python

I wanted to extract the customer name, customer reviews and time from 460 pages into CSV file.
Here is the 
[Url](http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061)

Answer (score 0):

if the site where you want scrap is always the same you can use Selenium, is more easy and fast, but have to know the html code of the page. Is a better solution when you have to scrap always the same pages

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\chromedriver.exe" # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = "http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061"
browser.get(url)

res = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.col-2.profile')
for item in res:
    try:
        user = item.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        print(user.get_attribute("href"))
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR", e)
```

you can also use xpath
check this site http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html